# aws-appsync gives version when package is updated

Tags: aws-appsync

aws-appsync version 4.1.5 gives error

this is my package.json file

```json
 "@apollo/client": "^3.5.10",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.3",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^8.3.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
    "aws-amplify": "^5.3.10",
    "aws-appsync": "^4.1.5",
    "graphql": "^16.4.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
    "native-base": "^3.4.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-apollo": "^3.1.5",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.4.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4"
```

when I tried to create `AWSAppSyncClient` , it gives error

```
 Error: Unable to resolve module stream from D:\Projects\node_modules\@smithy\util-stream\dist-cjs\getAwsChunkedEncodingStream.js: stream could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
  2 | Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
  3 | exports.getAwsChunkedEncodingStream = void 0;
> 4 | const stream_1 = require("stream");
    |                           ^
  5 | const getAwsChunkedEncodingStream = (readableStream, options) => {
  6 |     const { base64Encoder, bodyLengthChecker, checksumAlgorithmFn, checksumLocationName, streamHasher } = options;
  7 |     const checksumRequired = base64Encoder !== undefined &&
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (D:\Projects\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:139:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (D:\Projects\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:277:43)
    at Object.resolve (D:\Projects\atm-app\newATM4\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:169:21)
    at Graph._resolveDependencies (D:\Projects\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:473:35)
    at Graph._processModule (D:\Projects\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:261:38)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Graph._addDependency (D:\Projects\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:372:20)
    at async Promise.all (index 2)
    at async Graph._processModule (D:\Projects\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:322:5)
    at async Graph._addDependency (D:\Projects\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:372:20)
```

for aws-appsync package version  "aws-appsync": "^4.1.5",